# is there a way I can store the factorization machine model?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, collaborative-filtering

I am using https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM module, to predict move ratings. However, is there a way I can store (I am using django) the factorization machine after it is trained? Because right now (following the example), I would have to retrain the model everytime I restart the server.

Comment: AFAIK, the only "supported" way to persist a model from sklearn is pickle.  So you could probably pickle your factorization machine as well ...

Comment: I am able to store it with pickle, however, I am not able to predict using the stored model. It gives me zeroes only

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere? Also can you describe the size of your dataset? (number of instances, etc)

Comment: @greeness The very first example of pyFM's github Readme.md will fail with all pickle modes in python 2( <=mode 2) and python 3 (<= mode 4).

Comment: I see. In the FM model, the learned parameters are in `self.w` and `self.v`. Did you try to add a customized serialize() method to just pickle `w` and `v`, which I believe are just list of floats? Similarly we can add a customized unserialize() method to read `w` and `v` and assign them into `self.w` and `self.v`

Comment: Alternatively, did you try other implementations, like this one in TensorFlow? https://github.com/geffy/tffm

Comment: Thx for your answers. I haven't tried other implementations yet. What do you mean by customized serialize method? How would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). After you train your model, you can save a representation of the python object to a file, and reopen it when you need it.

Comment: It doesnt work. I get "can't pickle FM_fast objects"

Comment: Yeah, i tried to. I dont get any error msg, however, when I try to model.predict I get the wrong result.

Like predicting from the load gives me another results ( only zeros) than predicting without saving and loading.

Comment: @user3799968 You are right. Even with python 3 and pickle-mode 4 it fails (in the way you describe). You have to debug it yourself, create an issue on pyFMs github or try some advanced picklers like **dill**. It's a sad situation for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sklearn`. If your model is not huge, the built-in persistence model of python - pickle should work. There is an example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).

Comment: ah it doesnt work I get ths error msg: can't pickle FM_fast objects